# what are the differences between youtube urls. how to convert from one form to another using php code

Tags: php, iframe, youtube

I am trying to display youtube videos on my web page

here is my code

```
    <embed width=\"240\" height=\"320\" 
    src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uqjg0xSGA1c&start=3&end=16\"
    type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\">
    </embed>
```

the above code display only white background.

the similar code works fine

```
    <embed width=\"240\" height=\"320\" 
   src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k\"
    type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\">
  </embed>
```

**Notice different src's**

How can i convert one form to another form. in am using php script.

Also are there any other methods to play youtube videos on web page?

Comment: I would suggest to use either `parse_url()` or regular expressions to get the video ID.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the URL using `parse_url()`. Retrieve and parse the query string to find out the value of `v` and then generate the new URL using that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$parsedurl = parse_url("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uqjg0xSGA1c&start=3&end=16");
echo $parsedurl["query"]; // v=Uqjg0xSGA1c&start=3&end=16
$queryvars = explode("&", $parsedurl["query"]);
// Loop through each queryvar, split on "="
```

Comment: This won't work for the second example `http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k` . Unfortunately YouTube url are quite a pain in the ass to work with

Comment: I thought you only wanted to convert from the first form to the second

Comment: To go the other way you can apply the same idea, `parse_url()` to retrieve the path and then parse out the ID

Comment: Yes i understand many thanks for the logic. if will parse based on the type of url.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this regex (I know it's not the best solution) to fetch the video ID for a while and had no problems so far. It works for different url format, not only for the query string url:

```
if(preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $matches)
{
  $videoId = $matches[1];
}
```

When you have the video id, you can just build the url you want, even to fetch thumbnails.

Of course if you are targeting only query string urls, parse_url() is better, but if you need to deal with different formats (say, with a user supplied url for a CMS) you need to revert to regular expressions